# Sharing ViewPager between two tab

Tags: android

[image: Tab View Pager]

I have try many various way to share the viewpager but fail.Any Idea please

```
TabLayout topTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.topTabLayout);
topTabLayout.addTab(topTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
topTabLayout.addTab(topTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
topTabLayout.addTab(topTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));

TabLayout bottomTabLayout =(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottomTabLayout);
bottomTabLayout.addTab(bottomTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 4"));
bottomTabLayout.addTab(bottomTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 5"));
bottomTabLayout.addTab(bottomTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 6"));
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code snippets of your onPageChangeListener()

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EcyA2kaH. this is the longest version i try

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the word share in your question, what are you trying to achieve? are there 6 tabs in your viewpager such that tab 1 tab 2 tab 3 are at the top and the rest are at the bottom or some other setup, if you can elaborate, I may be able to help

Comment: I had two tab. One above and one below.  The ViewPager should contain all the page link. Since quite odd to me setupWithViewPager(viewPager); cannot call twice.. Any other way like touch listener or select i have try and not work..

Comment: last code i still try to figure out  is at http://pastebin.com/UmEn2sxN

Comment: @HafizanAziz Please explain what you want to achieve exactly? What's the use of having `TabLayout-1` and `TabLayout-2` having binded  to a single instance of a `ViewPager`? Why not two different viewpager?.

Comment: if you see my code, yes i have try two viewpager and also one.If you can show example which no need to share 1 view pager is great.For logical, why need two view pager at first place ?,if can share range what table layout can access it would be great

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do something that `TabLayout` was not designed for. Probably you need to build your own custom tab widget to get the behavior you want.

Comment: ViewPager is the (V)iew part of the MVC design pattern adopted. (C)ontroller and (M)odel is the adapter such as FragmentPagerAdapter. I think the thought process is to share the adapters, the data, rather than the ViewPager. In case you want to share the data between different Tabs, you can do that by setting the same adapter, setAdapter() method, to the different ViewPagers. In that case you need to design a "thread safe" adapter. As you are going out of flow, I am sure you will be ready to work on such challenges. Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is against google material guide line. You can read about it [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html).

Recently I had a custom `TabLayout` design work, I have red all the `TabLayout` code.
This is impossible to do with design support library.

Reflection is an option but leave you with a lot of work and at the end it doesn't what you needed exactly, because the design support library has not been designed for this.

I you want to do this still, you should consider creating a custom `TabLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code follow the steps:

1) Create layout for Activity :

```
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/job_layout"
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"/>



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">


            <com.xlsys.generic.view.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs1"
                />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>







2) Create two fragment for two tab if three Tab then create three fragment:

Fragment 1) 



 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import com.xlsys.generic.activities.R;


    public class JobCalender extends Fragment {



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inspection, container, false);
          return mView;
        }

    }





3) Create xml file for above fragment 

3) Same way create another fragment and xml file  for another tab.

4) Create Activity :




 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import com.xlsys.generic.fragments.Inspection_Fragment;
    import com.xlsys.generic.fragments.NC_Fragments;
    import com.xlsys.generic.view.SlidingTabLayout;
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class AddLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        private String mPagerItem[]={"Calender","Tab2"};

        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
        ViewPager pager;

        public String jobId,mTaskType,taskCreatedDate;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.addlocation);


            getWidgets();
            setWidgets();
            setWidgetsListener();

        }



        private void getWidgets() 

            pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
            mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout)findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs1);
        }

        private void setWidgets()
        {

            pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
            mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(pager);


        }



        private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

            int mNumOfTabs;
            public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return mPagerItem[position];
            }

            public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
                switch(pos) {
                    case 0:
                        JobCalender JobCalender_fragment=new JobCalender();
                        return JobCalender_fragment;
                    case 1:
                        NC_Fragments mNC_Fragments=new NC_Fragments();
                        return mNC_Fragments;

                    default:
                       JobCalender JobCalender_fragment=new JobCalender();
                        return JobCalender_fragment;

                }
            }
            public int getCount() {
                return mPagerItem.length;
            }
        }



    }
```

5) Add class SlidingTabLayout:

```
 your.package.name ;    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Point;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.Display;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    /**
     * To be used with ViewPager to provide a tab indicator component which give constant feedback as to
     * the user's scroll progress.
     * <p>
     * To use the component, simply add it to your view hierarchy. Then in your
     * {@link android.app.Activity} or {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} call
     * {@link #setViewPager(ViewPager)} providing it the ViewPager this layout is being used for.
     * <p>
     * The colors can be customized in two ways. The first and simplest is to provide an array of colors
     * via {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} and {@link #setDividerColors(int...)}. The
     * alternative is via the {@link TabColorizer} interface which provides you complete control over
     * which color is used for any individual position.
     * <p>
     * The views used as tabs can be customized by calling {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)},
     * providing the layout ID of your custom layout.
     */
    public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

        /**
         * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
         * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
         */
        public interface TabColorizer {

            /**
             * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
             */
            int getIndicatorColor(int position);

            /**
             * @return return the color of the divider drawn to the right of {@code position}.
             */
            int getDividerColor(int position);

        }

        private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
        private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
        private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

        private int mTitleOffset;

        private int mTabViewLayoutId;
        private int mTabViewTextViewId;

        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

        private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

        public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
        }

        public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);

            // Disable the Scroll Bar
            setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
            setFillViewport(true);

            mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

            mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
            addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }

        /**
         * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
         *
         * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
         * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} and {@link #setDividerColors(int...)} to achieve
         * similar effects.
         */
        public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
            mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
        }

        /**
         * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
         * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
         */
        public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
            mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
        }

        /**
         * Sets the colors to be used for tab dividers. These colors are treated as a circular array.
         * Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
         */
        public void setDividerColors(int... colors) {
            mTabStrip.setDividerColors(colors);
        }

        /**
         * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
         * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
         * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
         *
         * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
         */
        public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
        }

        /**
         * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
         *
         * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
         * @param textViewId id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
         */
        public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
            mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
            mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
         * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
         */
        public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

            mViewPager = viewPager;
            if (viewPager != null) {
                viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
                populateTabStrip();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
         * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
         */
        protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            textView.setWidth(size.x /2);

            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
            textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, then we can use the Theme's
                // selectableItemBackground to ensure that the View has a pressed state
                TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
                getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                        outValue, true);
                textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                // If we're running on ICS or newer, enable all-caps to match the Action Bar tab style
                textView.setAllCaps(true);
            }

            int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

            return textView;
        }

        private void populateTabStrip() {
            final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
            final OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View tabView = null;
                TextView tabTitleView = null;

                if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                    // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                    tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                            false);
                    tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
                }

                if (tabView == null) {
                    tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
                }

                if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                    tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
                }

                tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
                tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

                mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow();

            if (mViewPager != null) {
                scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
            }
        }

        private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
            final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
                return;
            }

            View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
            if (selectedChild != null) {
                int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

                if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                    // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                    targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
                }

                scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
            }
        }

        private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
            private int mScrollState;

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
                if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                    return;
                }

                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

                View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
                int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                        ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                        : 0;
                scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

                if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                    mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                            positionOffsetPixels);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                mScrollState = state;

                if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                    mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                    scrollToTab(position, 0);
                }

                if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                    mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
                }
            }

        }

        private class TabClickListener implements OnClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```